# Buy normally or as usual?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

What is the correct and succinct continuation of the phrase:

> Find an online store and buy [...]

*normally* or *as usual*?

I would use *normally*. However, *as usual* also seems correct.
The intended meaning is that once you find an online store, you can buy as you would usually do.

Comment: What's your question?  You seem to have already answered it yourself: either choice is fine?

Comment: To 'buy normally' would mean to behave normally at the counter. To 'normally buy' describes one's buying habits.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. I would normally take my item to the register, hand the cashier some money and receive some change that I would put in my pocket and then I would walk out of the store carrying my purchase in a bag.  How do I do any of that in an online store??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Buy in the usual way

I suggest this wording if you want to imply that the reader already knows how to do it in other circumstances, and needs reassurance that the actions need are the usual ones.

"Buy normally" slightly suggests to me that there might be an "abnormal" way for the reader to buy.

"Buy as usual" slightly suggests to me that the reader might already be in the habit of making this purchase in this manner. I believe from your question that the reader knows how to buy in an online shop, but not having reached it by this particular route. Therefore "buy in the usual way" might be easier for the reader to recognise as a recommendation that the action of buying is the familiar one, even if the route to reaching the purchase is unfamiliar.